# file upload code igniter..not working

Tags: codeigniter, upload

This is in my controller for file upload

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/b2b/banner-agent/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['file_name'] = "$banner2";
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->data();
$this->upload->do_upload();
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

is there any wrong with my code? The upload not working.

Comment: define `not working`. We need some error message to work on.

Comment: Whats in `do_upload()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can not simply call `do_upload` method before initializing and setting config variables for the upload class.

You need to modify your code like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/b2b/banner-agent/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['file_name'] = $banner2;
$this->load->library('upload'); //initialize
$this->upload->initialize($config); //Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class
$this->upload->do_upload(); // do upload
if($this->upload->do_upload()){
    $this->upload->data(); //returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded.
}
```

You can consult **Codeigniter wiki** for that too:

**http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html**

Hope this helps.