# file upload function does not working in codeigniter goddady hosting but in local machine work

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

I've some problem on uploading images and file in folder and database. The upload function does not work after I upload it into godaddy hosting but it can function in localhost. When I run it, it shows "fail to upload" message and data does not save in database and folder. I hope anyone can help me

This is my controller:

```
public function prosesupload()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './gambar/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|docx';
    $config['max_size']             = 10000;
    $config['max_width']            = 5000;
    $config['max_height']           = 5000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        echo 'fail to upload';
    }
    else
    {
        $img = $this->upload->data();
        $gambar = $img['file_name'];

        $data = array(

                'images' => $gambar, );

        $this->db->insert('arc', $data);
        redirect('arc/index');
    }

}
```

This is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('arc/prosesupload');?>

    <br>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /> </td>


    <td><button class="w3-button w3-right w3-light-grey" type="submit" 
    align="">Upload</button></a></td>


    </tr>
    <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

Comment: try to output upload error. so you may find out what is wrong. `$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());`

Comment: May be problem in your helper take a look $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

Comment: @Badiparmagi, i have do your code but it shows blank page

Comment: @omkara, did i need to do upload_helper.php? because i have do your code and it show message "file does not exist-helpers/upload_helper.php"

Comment: if there is linux hosting than check the permission of folder

Comment: @GopalBhuva, i used windows hosting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file upload code igniter..not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769709/file-upload-code-igniter-not-working)

Comment: @FaizatulNajihah, Set folder permission .

Answer (score 0):

folder.
It seems you are missing to given permission to upload folder.
    try to give full permission on folder and try it. Also make sure directory is created on path . 
Try to give full permission on folder and try it. Also make sure directory is created on path.

```
You should give name into do_upload
```

You should give name into do_upload

```
And few changes in code also :
```

And few changes in code also:

```
<input type="file" name="test_image" />



public function prosesupload()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './gambar/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|docx';
    $config['max_size']             = 10000;
    $config['max_width']            = 5000;
    $config['max_height']           = 5000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('test_image'))
    {
        echo 'fail to upload';
    }
    else
    {
        $img = $this->upload->data();
        $gambar = $img['file_name'];

        $data = array(

                'images' => $gambar, );

        $this->db->insert('arc', $data);
        redirect('arc/index');
    }

}
```

Comment: i've follow your code but it still error..my folder is in root directory "Project"

Comment: i've used print_r($_FILES) and it shows error fail to uploadArray ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => images (3).jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpF62A.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 16046 ) )..what should i do? i'm a newbie in codeigniter..